# Can we host Identity Server 4 in the same application with a client?

Tags: identityserver4

I have two straight questions about Identity Server 4. Can some please help me to understand them better. They are:

1) why we need to host Identity Server 4 separately?

2) Can we host Identity Server 4 in the same application with the client?

Comment: On a related note, in [a recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46146137/419956) I gave an example of _how_ you could possibly have server/client in the same .NET Core 2 app.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, we need to host Identity server separately as the main purpose of having an identity server is the power of Signle sign on. You can have many web client apps and can manage their login logic through one centralized server.

So, you can host the Identity server in client app technically, but it won't be the best use of identity server in my understanding!

Comment: Hi jay

Thanks for your response. I really appreciate if you clear below doubts:

1) In the above you have mentioned web clients. I am confused about how we handle the users records or db for different different clients.

2) Is the backend records of users for identity server for different client stored in the different dbs or in the same main db of client.

3) My scenario is i am planning a web application with android app so for a single tenant i would like to keep a separate db so whats the best way to implement id server 4 for the same