# Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

Beginner level query alert. [IdentityServer4 Tutorial](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) After going through the tutorials what I inferred was that-

1. I create an authorization server, whose job is to issue token for the client with proper authentication.
2. My Authorization Server runs first, and includes information and definitions of the API and client.
3. The API has an authentication middleware  that validates the incoming token to make sure if its coming from a trusted source and also its scope.
4. The client requests a token from the authorization server and then sends request to the API with the token received.

For all this, I had to run the authorization server first, the API next and then the Client. My requirement is that I don't need a start and stop server which runs separately to take care of authentication. I have one API and I need it to double as the authorization server too. Is this possible? Is it possible for the API to generate tokens, validate them and then tend to the requests, all the while using IdentityServer4.

Comment: Can't you just install the identity server packages into the same application as the API?

Comment: Yes I did, it worked. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update Jan 2020**: For a ASP.NET Core 3.1 example of using IdentityServer4 in the same project as ASP.NET Core API controllers, you can have a look at my [IdentityServer4 with MVC Controllers and AppInsights sample repo](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-identityserver4-with-appinsights/blob/master/SampleAppInsightsIdentity/Startup.cs). It's goal was to test AppInsights, but it does demonstrate a SPA stub that calls both OpenID endpoints (⚠ in a non-recommended wa, using client credentials), and controller endpoints.

---

Although typically the Auth Server will be separate from the Resource Server, this doesn't need to be the case. You can just add all of it to one application. Here's an example.

1. Create a new ASP.NET Core (I used 2.0) Web API application.
2. `Install-Package IdentityServer4 -Version 2.0.0-rc1` (at the time of writing rc1 is the version with .NET Core 2.x support)
3. `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer`
4. Set `[Authorize]` on `ValuesController` from the template
5. Add this code to `Configure(...)` in `class Startup` above `app.UseMvc()`:

   ```csharp
   // calls app.UseAuthentication() for us
   // See: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html
   app.UseIdentityServer();
   ```
6. Add this code to `ConfigureServices(...)` in `class Startup`:

   ```csharp
   services.AddIdentityServer()
       .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
       .AddInMemoryApiResources(new[]
       {
           new ApiResource
           {
               Name = "MyApi",
               ApiSecrets = { new Secret("supersecret".Sha256()) },
               Scopes = { new Scope("myapi") },
           }
       })
       .AddInMemoryClients(new[]
       {
           new Client
           {
               ClientId = "api",
               ClientSecrets = { new Secret("supersecret".Sha256()) },
               AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
               AllowedScopes = { "myapi" },
           }
       })
       .AddTestUsers(new List<TestUser>
       {
           new TestUser
           {
               SubjectId = "some-unique-id-12345678980",
               Username = "john",
               Password = "123456"
           }
       });

   services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddJwtBearer(opts =>
       {
           opts.Authority = "http://localhost:51689";
           opts.Audience = "MyApi";
           opts.RequireHttpsMetadata = !env.IsDevelopment();
       });
   ```

If you now <kbd>F5</kbd> the app it will show an empty page because of a "401 Unauthorized" response. You can also now check this endpoint: `http://localhost:51689/.well-known/openid-configuration` (with your dev port of course).

You can also do this now:

```bash
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:51689/connect/token \
  -H 'authorization: Basic YXBpY2xpZW50aWQ6c3VwZXJzZWNyZXQ=' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'username=john&password=123456&grant_type=password'
```

Note that the `authorization` header contains a base64 encoded string representing the string `"apiclientid:supersecret"`. This should give you a result like this:

```json
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjczODhkMjY0MDg4Y2NjOGRiZTcwODIzZGIxYzY3ZWNkIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1MDUwODE3OTAsImV4cCI6MTUwNTA4NTM5MCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MTY4OSIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjUxNjg5L3Jlc291cmNlcyIsIk15QXBpIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImFwaWNsaWVudGlkIiwic3ViIjoic29tZS11bmlxdWUtaWQtMTIzNDU2Nzg5ODAiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1MDUwODE3OTAsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwic2NvcGUiOlsibXlhcGkiXSwiYW1yIjpbInB3ZCJdfQ.sxWodlJKDJgjoOj-8njZ8kONOqiKgj3E5YlKXGX5cz-WqUK7RHKJacNX09D00Y8YtmZpkc5OrY0xzOx7UuSAtDku4oOX_1o38XEGJPBSJHdjqgVGSOU-hwDkzin8HSRJ0Kna1vM3ZzTh80cFTVhP8h903GAPRrAyV8PtRXnwV0CPel8NdvML6dV-mfDpGi0l7crp-TPnH4nIG0olpRYUPV5EsgCVMG9vswnOnKz3RPOGaU8yJy7_9mbQW5GHKfN0J6swiSt5rY3NKs_t1P9-tnCDKBOAafaXjLEO3Kx4fP4xTgwK92uKcEDDnRZo_-T0CkBxnSQm0oz1sUyrW8_3Pg",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

In addition to the option of switching to other authentication flows, you can also add a controller method like this:

```csharp
[Route("api/token")]
public class TokenController
{
    [HttpPost("request")]
    public async Task<JObject> Request(string username, string password)
    {
        var tokenClient = new TokenClient("http://localhost:51689/connect/token", "apiclientid", "supersecret");
        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(username, password);

        if (tokenResponse.IsError) { /* Log failed login attempt! */ } 

        return tokenResponse.Json;
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```bash
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:51689/api/token/request \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'username=john&password=123456'
```

This should give a similar response as above.

You can now provide this `access_token` insde a header `Authorization: Bearer access_token_should_go_here` like this:

```bash
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:51689/api/values \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjczODhkMjY0MDg4Y2NjOGRiZTcwODIzZGIxYzY3ZWNkIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1MDUwODIyODQsImV4cCI6MTUwNTA4NTg4NCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MTY4OSIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjUxNjg5L3Jlc291cmNlcyIsIk15QXBpIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImFwaWNsaWVudGlkIiwic3ViIjoic29tZS11bmlxdWUtaWQtMTIzNDU2Nzg5ODAiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1MDUwODIyODQsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwic2NvcGUiOlsibXlhcGkiXSwiYW1yIjpbInB3ZCJdfQ.hQ60zzEbZOSVpP54yGAnnzfVEks18YXn3gU2wfFgNB33UxQabk1l3xkaeUPTpuFdmFTm4TbVatPaziGqaxjzYgfdVoAwQ3rYJMuYzOh0kUowKxXTkquAlD13ScpvxrGeCXGxFTRHrxX2h-1hHGQ9j2y2f3-ESynzrCdxp5HEH1271BSYfQ7pZIzvyxxpbmOzzKDzdYfcJV6ocnOU4jXBhw6iOzqpR03zxxtjIjGbJd2QwWklBGqZlO_thdZZFi-t7zu5eC4wqRCYGGZYWOUC17_Btc_Irg2SsvLCUDzsaBw7AVgLpZ7YjF-RsVqIi6oxNQ2K0zllzUy8VbupbWKr5Q' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
```

And now you should get past the `[Authorize]` atribute. Yay!

You now have *one* web application, which acts as both an Auth Server and a Resource Server.

---

Fun fact: with the above example the `AddJwtBearer` options specify the application's own url as an `Authority`, making the app request from itself the public key to use for validating the tokens. You could instead also use code to directly provide this key to the authentication middleware.

Comment: Is there any downside of doing this in practice?

Comment: AFAIK nothing besides the obvious: if your Resource Server goes down, the ID server goes down (and vice versa).

Comment: Thanks again for this answer! I can't believe nobody else has up voted it yet. I searched heavily online about an example of how to do this and this is the most useful information I have got! Btw, in your code you set `ClientId = "api1"` and `ClientSecrets = { new Secret("supersecret".Sha256()) },` But the base64 string is encoded using `apiclientid:supersecret`; I think it should be encoded from `api:supersecret` instead as the format is "ClientId:ClientSecret"

Comment: @stt106 Thx for the positive comment :D. As for the possible mistake, I do remember wondering about the same thing a few months ago, but found that the code as it is in the answer would work. Does your proposed change also work? (I'd have to try but won't have time next 2 weeks or so :P)

Comment: The reason why I thought it was a 'mistake' is because I tried to follow your code format using `apiclientid:client secret` but it didn't work for me. Then I changed it to "ClientId:ClientSecret" format and it worked. Maybe this is due to identityserver4 package upgrade since your answer.