# Hosting IS4 and AspNet Core Identity's user management functions in the same web application?

Tags: identityserver4

I've read in some IS4 issues recently, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266667/can-we-host-identity-server-4-in-the-same-application-with-a-client), that hosting IS4 and a client in the same web application is not a tested or recommended scenario.  Does this also apply for when integrating AspNet Identity's **logged-in** workflows into IS4?

For example, it's understood that AspNet Identity's Account feature's controller, models and views from AspNet Identity are required so that IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity code can initiate the relevant UI, but is it okay to leave the Manage controller in the same web application so as to provide a self-service feature, or should this functionality be moved to a separate web application?

For IS3 I created a separate web app that contained user profile functions (Manage controller), plus admin for the IS3 configuration and user management.  This app was configured as a client and the IS3 web app itself had no client config or logged-in workflows.  Is this the preferred architecture for re-using the Manage controller functionality?

Ideally, I'd like to keep AspNet Identity functionality together with IS4 in the one web app and have a separate web app for admin of config and users.  Just want to be certain I'm not opening up a security vulnerability by doing so.

Comment: Don't think there's any *specific* security issues with having both Authentication and Resources in one application, apart from of course the fact that if one gets hacked they are both hacked. It's mostly a matter of separating concerns, and possibly reusing an Auth server amongst multiple different clients.

Comment: Yes I agree but I'm specifically asking about the aspnet identity "manage" controller functionality rather than any client. As for separation of concerns, this is normally contained in the same process as the account controller so I'm asking if that is still okay or, as a logged-in workflow, should it be hosted separately and protected through an IS4 client config?

Comment: This is OK. I think what the referenced github issue wants to say is that things get unnecessary complex when hosting applications in the same app as the identity provider. What you are trying to achieve is totally fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Care to answer the question and I'll declare it answered?